# Jquery $(this) wrong scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a problem and perhaps I get help.

I have a navigation and when I click on a navigation point I want to get the id form the clicked navigation point.

My problem is, that I'm not getting back the ID with $(this). I get the whole index.js back.

The crazy thing is, when I do it with this following snippet, it works.
But this is not my favourite way to do this. I like the second way, because it's more cleaner.

```
    $('.menuContent p').on('click', function () {
        var clickedMenuEntry = $(this).attr('id');

        switch (clickedMenuEntry) {
            case 'yourData': yourDataSite();
                break;
        }
    });
```

Here starts the way which doesn't work.

```
    <div class="col-md-6 menuContent">
        <p id="yourData"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Deine Daten</p>
        <p id="yourSuccess"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>Deine Erfolge</p>
        <p id="surveys"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Umfragen</p>
        <p id="yourMatches"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Turniere an denen du teilnimmst</p>
        <p id="money"><i class="fa fa-money"></i>Jahresbeitrag / Budget</p>
        <p id="yourStatics"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>Statistik</p>
    </div>




(function () {
"use strict";

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Verarbeiten der Cordova-Pause- und -Fortsetzenereignisse
    document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);
    $('.appIsLoading').remove();
    bindEvents();
};

/*
* @return {void}
*/ 
function bindEvents() {
    var $body = $('body');
    $body.on('click', '.menu', showAndHideNavigation);
    $body.on('click', '.menuContent p', switchToRequestedSite);
}

/*
* @return {void}
*/
function showAndHideNavigation() {
    var $menuContent = $('.menuContent');
    var statusOfMenuContent = parseInt($('.menuContent').css('left'));

    if (statusOfMenuContent < 0) {
        $menuContent.css('left', '0%');
    } else {
        $menuContent.css('left', '-78%');
    }
}

/*
* @return {String}
*/
function getClickedNavigationEntry() {
    return $(this).attr('id');
}

/*
* @return {void}
*/
function switchToRequestedSite() {
    var clickedMenuEntry = getClickedNavigationEntry();

    switch (clickedMenuEntry) {
        case 'yourData': yourDataSite();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getClickedNavigationEntry()` doesn't inherit `this` when called inside `switchToRequestedSite()`

Can use `bind()` or just pass in element as argument for better readability

```
function switchToRequestedSite() {

  // pass element to fn
  var clickedMenuEntry = getClickedNavigationEntry(this);

  // or much simpler
  var clickedMenuEntry = this.id;

  switch (clickedMenuEntry) {
    case 'yourData':
      yourDataSite();
      break;
  }
}

function getClickedNavigationEntry(el) {
  return el.id;
}
```

Not sure why you need a function just to return an element ID

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this

```
function bindEvents() {
    var $body = $('body');
    $body.on('click', '.menu', showAndHideNavigation);
    $body.on('click', '.menuContent p', function(){
        switchToRequestedSite($(this));
    });
}

/*
* @return {void}
*/
function showAndHideNavigation() {
    var $menuContent = $('.menuContent');
    var statusOfMenuContent = parseInt($('.menuContent').css('left'));

    if (statusOfMenuContent < 0) {
        $menuContent.css('left', '0%');
    } else {
        $menuContent.css('left', '-78%');
    }
}

/*
* @return {void}
*/
function switchToRequestedSite(clickedMenuEntry ) {

    switch (clickedMenuEntry) {
        case 'yourData': yourDataSite();
            break;
    }
}
```